# "htmlToPlaintext" AngularJS (1.3.15) Custom Filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create a custom filter , but despite following the correct structure I think something is wrong.

```js
angular.module('App', [])

.filter("htmlToPlaintext", function() {
 return function(text) {
     return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
 }
})

.controller ('mainCtrl',['$scope','$filter', function($scope,$filter){
    $scope.items=[
        {id: '1', title: '<b>Chicago</b>'},
        {id: '2', title: '<b><i>New York</i></b>'},
        {id: '3', title: '<div><p>Washington</p></div>'}
    ];    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{item.title | htmlToPlainText}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your filter name is htmlToPlaintext: {{item.title|htmlToPlain}} ->{{item.title|htmlToPlaintext}}

Comment: Also you should not have a semicolon after the filter. Sugessted an edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ideally you should declare your filter within it's own module and then inject it into the App module. But you can attach the filter to the App module directly. Below is a working example:

```js
    angular.module('App', [])
    .filter("htmlToPlaintext", function() {
        return function(input) {
          return input.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
        }
      })
      .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.items = [{
            id: '1',
            title: '<b>Chicago</b>'
          }, {
            id: '2',
            title: '<b><i>New York</i></b>'
          }, {
            id: '3',
            title: '<div><p>Washington</p></div>'
          }];
        }
      ]);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="App">
      <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          {{item.title | htmlToPlaintext}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You don't need to use `$filter` as you are using HTML Template Binding.

Comment: Is there any way that does not have to declare the module ?

Comment: I would like you to see this question please , that does not happen, in spite of thumb 2 filters does not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447184/going-through-the-filter-angularjs-htmlplaintotext/30447245#30447245

Answer (score -1):

Extracting text from HTML via Regexps it not good idea. Especially if you encounter with something weird, like this html

```
<span>2 < 3<span>
```

Your filter gives you `2`, but actually here should be `2 < 3`.
If you want to manage all possible cases properly, you should use some DOM-API:

```
.filter("htmlToPlaintext", function() {
    return function(text) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        return div.textContent || "";
    }
})
```

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822486/1297743) for similar question to know more.

Comment: angular.element(text).text()  can also be used