# going through the filter AngularJS? HTMLPLAINTOTEXT

Tags: reference, angularjs-filter

In my web: http://miguelsirna.com i applied a filter in the post.php file, declared for angular. within my local server if I expands the content.

Answer (score 0):

http://miguelsirna.com/include/json/posts.php this is the module 
I applied php, below I leave the picture as it was my first attempt , as you can see I've implemented a function strip_tags()
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcXhs.png

Comment: your posts.php should be just returning json. Your angular filter should be in a js file, not returned by posts.php.